# Re-enabling tab key after disabling on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, qualtrics

I want to disable the use of the TAB key to change focus between text boxes on a page. The following code works great, but I find that the TAB key remains disabled on the next pages as well (on a Qualtrics survey, specifically). 
How can I re-enable it on the next page? Thanks!

```js
$(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {   //tab pressed
        event.preventDefault(); // stops its action
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean pages? Is it different divs on the same document?

Answer (score 0):

Change document to .Skin:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    jQuery('.Skin').on('keydown', function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode == 9) {   //tab pressed
        event.preventDefault(); // stops its action
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, @t-gibbons, but I don't seem to get this code to work. Do I need to do anything else than add it to the JS of the relevant blocks?

Comment: Sorry, it got messed up when I copied&pasted (missing a )};).  I've updated it, so try it again.